# javascript - Getting correct scroll position on window.onerror

Tags: javascript, scroll, onerror

I'm trying to show errors in a custom box, with some info (line number, file name...), inside a DIV that overlays page's body and avoids interactions with elements outside the box.

This is CSS of the DIV:

```
overlayStyle = {
    'position': 'absolute',
    'top': '0px',
    'left': '0px',
    'height': '100%',
    'width': '100%',
    'backgroundColor': 'rgba(199,199,199,0.7)',
    'display': 'block',
    'zIndex': '1000',
    'textAlign': 'center',
    'paddingTop': '5%'
}
```

I'm testing this by making an AJAX call to a file that not exists in the HEAD section of the document so the box is opening as the document loads.
This is the onerror handler:

```
window.onerror = function ( msg, url, line ) {
    error ( msg, url, line );
    return true;
}
```

And that's a part of the script that creates the box:

```
var root = document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement : document.body;
root.scrollTop = 0;

document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
```

Here I scroll the document to top in order to show only the overlaying DIV, which has 0,0 coords.

If I close the error box, scroll down the page and send an F5, page reloads scrolled to bottom but overlaying DIV is positioned at 0,0 so I just see its bottom part.

That's because scrollTop position (I tried window.scrollY too) is 0 so root.scrollTop = 0; won't produce any effect.

Any way to position the DIV correctly (please no jQuery)?

Here is complete code:

```
function error ( msg, url, line ) {
    var overlay = document.createElement ( 'DIV' ),
    scrollPos = 0,
    root = document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement : document.body,
    overlayId = 'divErrorOverlay',
    overlayStyle = {
            'position': 'absolute',
            'top': '0px',
            'left': '0px',
            'height': '100%',
            'width': '100%',
            'backgroundColor': 'rgba(199,199,199,0.7)',
            'display': 'block',
            'zIndex': '1000',
            'textAlign': 'center',
            'paddingTop': '5%'
    },
    errHead = null,
    errBody = null;

    overlay.setAttribute ( 'id', overlayId );
    for ( var i in overlayStyle ) overlay.style [ i ] = overlayStyle [ i ];

    scrollPos = root.scrollTop; //I use this to restore position when box is closed
    root.scrollTop = 0;

    document.body.appendChild ( overlay );
    document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';

    //Calls to methods that creates header and body
}
```

Comment: Any reason for not simply using `fixed` position?

Comment: Not really but I have a a couple of elements on page's top left corner that I want to be visibile under the overlaying DIV. Btw I can move them if this is the only/simplest way.